# how to go to particular line number in java class file

Tags: java

I am trying to build an agent that when exception comes it will tell which class,method and which object is causing the problem using the catalina log file where exception stack trace will be there which has line number in java file.I tried decompiling the class files i have in the war but they don't give exactly the same file espacially when there is inner class in that class so line number is not same as that in java file.Any ideas how should i go about it ? or any different approach i should follow to achieve it?I just need to go at exactly same line in the class file

Comment: decompiling a class file will not give u the same source file. different decompiler has a different interpretation of the same byte file.

Comment: If you decompiled it (and don't have source), then recompile what you decompiled and use the decompiled source as reference.

Comment: If you want to find the line in the source code, then you need the source code.  You can just package the source as a jar file and include it in the war file.